# How can I add space above and below an ImageView in a row in a TableView?

Tags: alignment, constraints, xcode10

The row height in this table view is 54.  The ImageView Height is 44.  I'd like 5 above and below the ImageView (some spacing the image so that they aren't touching each other).  Basically, centering the ImageView, vertically, in the row (or ContentView).  No matter what I've tried, the image is always anchored in the top left corner of the row (since its a music app, it has to run on a phone, so I don't have an image for the result).  I'm embarrassed to say that I've spent hours trying to accomplish this.  I'd appreciate any help.  Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was right, there was another place that was forcing the image into the top left corner.  It was in the code when setting the contents of a row as shown below.  I wrote that part a long time ago when I knew even less about Swift (the goal was to make sure the image gets scaled.  It may not be necessary though.  I'll test the code without it.  Still, thank you Zaya for taking the time to help!

```
        let albumArtwork = rowItem.representativeItem?.artwork
        let tableImageSize = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10) // This doesn't matter, it gets resized below
        let cellImage: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44)) // The albumImageView is 44 by 44
```

Comment: Ah, I'm very glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, this is how I would set up my constraints. First, I would set the width constraint on the image view to be 44. [Note: I set my row height to be 54 just like yours.] Then I would set the aspect ratio constraint on the image view to be 1:1 (assuming you want a square image). Then, I would put the image view and the label to be in a horizontal stack view. If you bundle everything up in a stack view, I find that you have to worry about less constraints (the stack view will take care of the spacing between the image view and label although you can adjust accordingly if needed). Then I would add leading and trailing constraints to the stack view. And then finally, center the stack view vertically in the container.

Hope this helped. Good luck!

[image: Image of simulator showing stack view]

[image: Image of storyboard showing constraints on stack view]

Comment: I really appreciate your help!!!  But it didn't work.  I believe that Apple set out to make constraints to be extremely difficult.  StackView created more problems.  I still can't figure out why I tried to set the row height to 54 and XCODE makes it 53.5.  I'm mean what?

Comment: StackView didn't take care of the spacing between the two object, it put them right next to each other and locked them in.

Comment: My ImageView has a height of 44 and my Label has a height of 24.  Too much math for XCODE, because it can't handle that.  I've gotten to the point where I can get the label centered in the row (without StackView), but not the ImageView, no chance.

Comment: I can actually drag the ImageView to the left of the Label, execute the code, and XCODE puts it back on the right anchored in the upper left corner of the row.  In most development systems, I'd say that that is a clue to the issue, but not here.

Comment: With no constraints on the ImageView or Label, the following happens.  Start with the Label: x = 49, y = 0, width = 271, height = 24.  I can change y to say 15, run the code and the Label moves down by 15.  Perfect, that's what I'd expect.  But if I try to change y or even x on the ImageView, nothing changes, nothing, it's stays stuck to the upper left corner.

Comment: I even tried the following.  Shorten the existing Label and move it over to the left.  Move the ImageView towards the center.  Add a new Label to the View and put it to the left of the ImageView.  No constraints on these 3 objects.  Then I ran the code with no constraints, yup the ImageVIEW was put back to the upper left corner ... again.  There must be something, somewhere that's making this happen.

Comment: Found it.  I was forcing it in the code when setting the contents of the cell.  Zaya, thank you for your help!